# Call PHP script from another with arguments and get output

Tags: php, shell

I have a php script, let's call it `one.php`. This calls a second php script `two.php` with some arguments. Right now my code in `one.php` looks like this:

```
shell_exec("php ./two.php" . ' ' . escapeshellarg($var1) . ' '.      
escapeshellarg($var2) . ' '. escapeshellarg($var3));
```

This works fine (although I don't like it), but now I want to get some values that are computed in `two.php`.

I colud use `include()` or `require()` to get access to all the variables, but I want to use `two.php` in more than just one script - without having to use the same variable names in every script that calls `two.php` (which I had to because of the scope of the variables in `include()`).

My php skills are quite poor, so: Is there a way to send variables of a called script to the calling script or something like this? Or maybe another way of calling `two.php`.

**Update**: Using a function did it. Thanks!

Comment: Define a function in `two.php` that does whatever it should do. Have your scripts `include`/`require` the file, and call the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Calling another script" via `shell_exec` is a pretty bad idea. Instead, `two.php` should contain a bunch of **functions or classes** which you can `include` and call anytime:

```
include 'two.php';

$data = func_from_two($var1, $var2, $var3);
```

Learn to program using [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) and [classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php), that's the only sane way to go.